# how can I quantize a datetime index, in Pandas, and provide an operation per column?

Tags: python, pandas

let's assume I have this data, the index is a datetime type.

```
timestamp                a   b
2020-09-04 00:00:00.000  1   True
2020-09-04 00:00:01.212  2   False
2020-09-04 00:00:05.560  3   True
2020-09-04 00:00:06.590  4   True
2020-09-04 00:00:12.652  5   True
```

I'd like to have my index quantized to, let's say, 5s but I would like to apply a different function to each column.
For example column A will be a sum and column B will be an And operation

the output would be:

```
timestamp                a   b
2020-09-04 00:00:00.000  3   False
2020-09-04 00:00:05.000  7   True
2020-09-04 00:00:10.000  5   True
```

what would be the syntax for this? I can't seem to find that in the doc (a link to the doc if there is something clear about it would be great)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Resampler.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html) with `sum` and [`Series.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html):

```
df = df.resample('5S').agg({'a':'sum', 'b':'all'})
print (df)
                     a      b
timestamp                    
2020-09-04 00:00:00  3  False
2020-09-04 00:00:05  7   True
2020-09-04 00:00:10  5   True
```

You can create custom function returnes aggregated values, e.g.:

```
def f(x):
    return (x ** 2).sum()

df = df.resample('5S').agg({'a':f, 'b':'all'})
print (df)
                      a      b
timestamp                     
2020-09-04 00:00:00   5  False
2020-09-04 00:00:05  25   True
2020-09-04 00:00:10  25   True
```

Comment: can I provide custom functions for the aggregation?

Comment: @Thomas - sure, give em a sec.